# Call pagereference method from Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Can I call pagereference method from trigger.
I tried to call but I got nullPointerException.

Comment: why do you event want to do that ?

Comment: Actually I am creating an order from custom button and passing some parameter in url.
In my class I want to get url parameter.

Comment: you should refactor the code so that both the trigger and VF controller share some common service

Comment: Can we see the structure and intent of your code ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really do this. In [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36311/redirect-after-a-new-record-is-save-from-trigger) post you can find some explanations why. But basically trigger runs behind the scene so users can't see it and be redirected from there.

Comment: Basically i want to do some dml operation based on parameter passed url

Comment: Are you passing that parameter to a VF page or to a standard detail page?

Comment: I am passing the parameter in standard detail page

Comment: Then I would recommend changing your logic, because workarounds might be difficult here. For example you can create a custom setting and store there that parameter Id of the record and Id of the running user.

Comment: Basically I am creating one Order from custom java script button, based on the parameter passed in URL I want to perform certain operation in class. As I am passing URL in standard page, I can not do custom logic.

If it is not possible, then is there any way to find out from where the Order record is getting created i.e. either via Order Tab, Account related list or Custom button and based on condition I want to perform some operations

Comment: I think this is not possible too. You can also create a new field and populate it from URL with your parameter, but this is not very secure as users can put something else in that new field too. Here is info how to populate field from URL http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/